# How to find global mouse hooks in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, mouse

I've got an unusual issue on my machine at the moment. Whenever i scroll, with any mouse, it becomes very jumpy (scrolls up and down, although im only trying to scroll down).

**So i was wondering if theres any application that can detect global mouse hooks in the system? (Windows must manage at the very least at kernel level).**

Extra information:

```
- Ive ran Hijackthis, InjectDll, Autoruns and nothing unusual is starting up
- I installed Wiz Mouse later, and it helps, but only helps, doesn't completely repair the issue (which makes me believe that theres another application fighting for control)
- I've uninstalled/reinstalled mouse drivers.
- Running Windows 7601
- Tried using several different USB mouses, same issue (primary mouse, Roccat Kane+)
- Clean install, no OEM, custom built machine (quick specs, ssd, i7 2700k, 16gb ram, 460 gtx, Asus P8Z68 deluxe)
```

If anyone has any suggestions that could help that would be much appreciated as well.

SIDENOTE: I'm a programmer primarily, and making mouse hooks is easy, but I'm not entirely sure if theres a method of viewing the systems currently active hooks.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

I thought of a way of figuring it out, and i think it almost worked.
What i did was bust out Process Explorer, used the find handle/dll function.
Looked for 'hook.dll'. This found several process's, i killed all of the process's using this, scrolling performance was BETTER, but not perfect. (although an odd one was my Bluetooth driver application, btvstack.exe). So now i'm thinking it could be Driver side? (which i think may by pass hook.dll), or there may be another dll in play here that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Didn't you mention it happens with any mouse? Blue tooth, wireless, USB wired? Is that correct? Your edit suggests drivers, which is possible, but for all types of mouses? Do you have a PS/2 connection you could try?

Comment: Is this a home built rig or a Dell, etc? What specific model? Is it the OEM install of the OS or a clean install without all the OEM crap?

Comment: Home built, clean install. I haven't tried PS/2 mouses, but i dont have any around any more :(. But it does happen with all USB mouses.